# Can Git change files on checkout?

Tags: java, git

Does Git ever change files on checkout?   I'm experiencing behavior where I check out a branch, and **without touching anything** I suddenly have six or eight changed files.

These files are marked as "not staged for commit" and they are not files that I had already edited on an existing branch.

I suspect it's connected to a "line endings" setting discrepancy but I haven't been able to isolate it.   Here are all the Git settings (except for stuff like user.name and things like that):

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
core.autocrlf=true
core.excludesfile=C:\Users\username\Documents\gitignore_global.txt
merge.renormalize=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, yes, it can: if you checkout a branch, git will ensure that the working tree reflects that branch's contents -- should that mean changing line endings if the line endings are not the same in the files git has recorded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `git diff -b` (diff ignoring whitespace changes). If the diff comes back empty then it's probably all due to the line-ending conversions like you suspect.

Comment: @user1071914 - `core.autocrlf=false` ?